# Import error in Django, No module names views

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-views

I am trying to develop a job portal in Django. As I am new to Django, I am not able to figure out why import error is getting displayed upon page hit, after deploying it on server. It was however working fine when I was running and testing in eclipse environment.

Here is the project tree structure for your reference. I know its quite long.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, MeraJob is the main project name and accounts, companies, MeraJob, students are applications inside it.

I deployed this structure and when I hit, I get this error.
[image]

I have ensured all the urls.py files have imported views.py using `from views import *` or simply `import views`. I can't figure out what the problem is, can someone help me out in this regard? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Here is the my `MeraJob/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
import settings
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login_view'),url(r'^password/reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change'),
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT }),
url(r'^logout/$', logout_page),
url(r'^accounts/password/reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change'),
url(r'^password-changed/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done'),

url(r'^$', main_page),
url(r'^contact/$', contact_page),
url(r'', include('companies.urls')),
url(r'', include('miscellaneous.urls')),
url(r'', include('students.urls')),
)
```

Comment: try: `from .views import *` or `from accounts.views import *`

Comment: can you show your `MeraJob/urls.py` ?

Comment: @techEnthusiast inside the apps `from .views import *` should work fine.

Comment: @karthikr Here it is..

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from views import *
import settings
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',....)

Comment: what is the error _after_ you changed it to `from .views import *` - Also, when asked for more info, editing the question might be a better option

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yesh I tried the same, but the error remains!

Comment: @karthikr The error still remains the same!

Comment: can you move the pyc files and try again (It could be a stale pyc file issue)

Comment: No luck again! They aren't getting generated again either!

Comment: Where is main_page defined in urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly problem!
I missed to observe that the python file (views.py) didn't have read permissions for others!

Did a chmod appropriately and it worked! Thanks for other suggestions!!!

Comment: from app_name import  views works fine to me too. =)

Answer (score 0):

try from . import views
it would be easier if you posted your urls.py

Comment: bth it's not a good approach to use import *, it's better to explicitly import your modules. From "Two scoops of django": The reason for this is to avoid implicitly loading all of another Python module’s locals into and over our current module’s namespace, which can produce unpredictable and sometimes catastrophic results.

Comment: try adding views. to functions                                         url(r'^$', views.main_page),
url(r'^contact/$', views.contact_page),